# How to get back my split-screen after I lost connection with "screen"

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

I was executing the `screen` command with a split window in my CentOS server, then I lost connection to it. I reconnected to my server and I did `screen -r` to get my screen back but now I don't see them split, I only see the first screen and I have to switch to my other screen with the ctrl+a+space. How can I put them as they were before? Is there a way?

Comment: Try `tmux`, you will like it my friend. You can get disconnected from a session and come right back to your exact session and layout.

Comment: unfortunately splits in `screen` do not persist after a connection loss or deliberately detach.